# How to fix my while loop with if statements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hey i am working on a guessing game project with javascript that entails inputing a  number into a prompt "Give me a number between 1 and 10." Instructions are to incorporate the following:

while the guess is not equal to the target
Prompt for a new guess
If the guess is less than the target
print "too low!"
else If the guess is greater than the target
print "too high!"
else
print "You got it!"

So I have my while loop and if conditional statements but i don't know how to contain my if statements inside my while loop. My actual results just prompts me to Guess again repeatedly without alerting too high! or too low! My else statement when guessing the right number seems to work though. Thank you.

```js
let min = 1;
let max = 10;
let target = Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
target = Math.floor(target) + min;

let guess = (0);

guess = prompt("Give me a number between 1 and 10");
console.log("Your guess is" + guess);


while (guess != target) {
  prompt("Guess again");
  console.log(guess);

}
if (guess < target) {
  alert("too low!");
  console.log("too low guess", guess);

} else if (guess > target) {
  alert("too high!");
  console.log("too high guess", guess);

} else {
  alert("You got it!");
}
```

Comment: You are not reassigning the guess value, and result of prompt is always a string or null, so you should convert it to a number as well

Comment: _"My actual results just prompts me to Guess again repeatedly without alerting too high! or too low!"_ - Because the `if ... else ...` part is not _in_ the `while` loop

Comment: You have to put the if..else stuff inside the while block, not after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is currently doing this:

1. Forever: ask "guess again"
2. After 'forever' is over (which is never!) check the value of `guess`. Furthermore, the value of `guess` is the same as the first time the question as asked.

You'll want this:

1. Forever: ask "guess again"
2. After "guess again", *check and store* the stored value of the last answer.
3. If the answer is correct stop the forever running loop.

But what is also important: make sure `prompt` returns a number, because anything could be entered in a text prompt.

So that would be:

```
// See Note 1.
guess = parseInt(prompt("Give me a number between 1 and 10"), 10);
console.log("Your guess is" + guess);

// 1. Do something forever
while (guess != target){
    // 2. store the last answer
    guess = parseInt(prompt("Guess again"), 10);
    console.log(guess);
    
    // 2b. check the last answer
    if (guess < target){
        alert("too low!");
        console.log("too low guess", guess);
    }else if (guess > target){
        alert("too high!");
        console.log("too high guess", guess);
    }
    // 3. If the answer is correct, `guess === target` so the loop will end.
}

// See Note 2.
alert("You got it!");
```

Note 1: If the player enters something that can't be turned into an integer, `parseInt(, 10)` will return `NaN` (not a number). You can test that: `isNaN(123)` / `isNaN(NaN)`.

Note 2: Your application will not show a message if the player gets it correct in one go, because "you got it" was inside the loop. If the answer was right the first time, the loop would never be entered. Put the message outside the loop to fix that.